# Building Maven project doesn't create a jar?

Tags: java, maven

So, I tried making another project depending on my base project, it worked and now for some reason my base project won't build correctly.

Whenever I build my maven project, no jar is outputted anywhere. I checked my build path, and the target folder.

My pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>...</groupId>
    <artifactId>...</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>

    <repositories>
        ...
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        ...
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${basedir}</directory>
                <includes>
                    ...
                </includes>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>target/</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>...</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Now, with my original builds they still had the target folder for some reason, but now nothing is built at all.

Comment: Did adding `<packaging>jar</packaging>` in your pom help?

Comment: *Whenever I build my maven project* How exactly did you do this?

Comment: What's your Maven goal setting?

Comment: @chrylis I build it through Intellij, should of specified but too late so whatever.

Comment: @LHCHIN I have no idea, I'm really new to Maven and Intellij does it for me, I have command line set to "package" cause a guild told me to do that, and I use the default Intellij run profile other than that.

Comment: Maven doesn't have a concept called "build". `compile` is a phase along the route to `package`, which builds the jar.

Comment: @chrylis Oh, good to know.

Comment: The first thing is to follow convention over configuration so remove resources configuration and the configuration for maven-jar-plugin cause it's already bound to the life cycle and just try a plain `mvn clean package` on command line and see if there is no error/warning etc. afterwards take a look into target folder...Why have you added repositories in your pom file? Are within a company ?

Comment: @khmarbaise No, I am not with a company, I am trying to work on a library that requires a compiled jar depending on it at runtime, and it is far easier to keep it local than to figure out how to make a maven repo. But why would I not add repositories, how else would I get libraries at repositories?

Comment: If you work not in a company you have Maven Central and everything you need should be there if it's not you should setup a repository manager and don't pollute your pom's files with this...apart from making the configuration/order etc. easier.

Comment: I don't see a reason to set up a dedicated server for downloads just from me to download a single jar, which has tons of downloads.